# Searching a List

Tags: java

Lets say I have a list and I am trying to look up a Class element in it, from which I only know one (unique) attribute.

```
public static List<Achievement> listAchievements;
String idAchievement = "5764e35";
```

This is obviously not working

```
listAchievements.indexOf(idAchievement );
```

Neither is this

```
Achievement ach(idAchievement);
listAchievements.getIndexOf(ach);
```

and the workaround is not pretty

```
 for (Achievement achievement : listAchievements) {
        if (achievement.resourceID().equalsIgnoreCase(idAchievement)) {
            // STUFF
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And your question is? The "workaround" is pretty much the only option, unless you're open to using [a different data structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: I wonder if we have a getIndexOf(Object obj) method in List interface in java.

Comment: Correct method name is indexOf http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have isn't a workaround, it's the solution.

You could abstractify it with lambda-like behavior, and this and that... but in the end, if you're trying to search a list for an element that has a given attribute, there's nothing you can do but to iterate over the list until you find an element with that given attribute.

If you need to find Acchievments by ID more directly, a `Map<String,Achievement>` might be a better choice if the IDs are unique (which you say they are).

Comment: Mostly correct, just saying that I was using a list because that's what the external library was giving me to work with.

Comment: @EfEs Worth noting Vipul's answer, too. I was assuming the list was in the order you wanted, which is not ID-order. But if you can order the list, that can get you down to a binary search. There's overhead in sorting the list, though, so this approach is best if you can sort once and then search multiple times; if you need to do a sort per search, it won't be worthwhile.

Answer (score 4):

There is no other way than to loop over the elements until you find the one you're looking for. You could use Guava's support for predicates:

```
Achievement a = Iterables.find(list, new Predicate<Achievement>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Achievement input) {
        return input.resourceID().equalsIgnoreCase(idAchievement)
    }
});
```

but the end result is the same.

Or you could maintain a separate `Map<String, Achievement>` in addition to your list, or use a `LinkedHashMap<String, Achievement>` instead of your list, which would achieve O(1) search instead of O(n).

Comment: I want to split the "correct" between you and yshavit because your answer is also very informative, but he has less karma so he gets it. Ill upvote you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

1) you have to sort your list using static void sort(List,Comparator).
2) use static int binarySearch(List,Key,Comparator).

These two method are of java.util.Collections

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a list there's not much more to do. But if this is something that is done often you may want to consider creating a HashMap or similar instead (from achievementId to achievement).

Answer (score 0):

To make such efficient you'll either have to use Map of idAchievement to Achievement, or make sure your collection is sorted by idAchievement attribute and then use Collections.binarySearch().